# Spoofing routing location from Canada too USA

Tags: networking, routing

My ISP located in Texas now routes me through a router located in Canada.

I live in Arizona, USA & can't do business with some websites that block traffic from Canada.

Some responses I've received from websites is `I'm located in a foreign country`.

My ISP will not change back to USA.  They are very uncooperative.

Can I spoof my location to show USA ?

Comment: Routing THRU Canada is not an issue.  Please post a traceroute with your question as there is more to this story.

Comment: How about VPN ? Or leaving a very uncooperative ISP for a cooperative one ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.  The way to "take this into your own hands" is to get a VPN which is connected in America - that will give you an IP address which is located in America.

You can possibly use a proxy to do a similar thing, however it may not work as well if it adds X-Forwarded-For headers, which would be a common practice.

The alternative is to track down geolocation databases and get your IP range updated - this will take a while and is probably quite a difficult process, although many providers do provide Correction Requests.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514749/best-ip-to-country-database for some providers, also

[Maxmind Correction Request](https://support.maxmind.com/geoip-data-correction-request/)
IP2Location Page with email for Update and Corrections[enter link description here](http://www.ip2location.com/contact)

Of-course, you could presumably change to another ISP (or use mobile data or an alternative connection).

Comment: Just so its clear, GeoIP invariably works off your IP address, which is then looked up in a database.  Change your IP address and you change your apparent location.